# iOS: Color-changing circle button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm trying to make a button that will show/hide a color-selection slider. That's the easy part.

What I am not sure how to do is to make the button be a circle with an outline (say black) and the fill be the color shown in the slider. As the user moves the slider, the color of the circle should change accordingly.

I am new to iOS development, so probably I am approaching this all wrong. I would really appreciate any ideas even they are completely different from what I have here.

I started to approach this with a subclass using QuartzCore layers, and the result is decent, but there are issues/things that bother me:

1. For some reason I get no highlight state when pressing the button
2. It's obviously odd to use rounded corners to achieve a circle
3. Unfortunately, it seems at the point were I draw the layers, the button is not laid out yet so I have had to hardcode the radius instead of making it based on the button size.

So, yeah I hardly think this approach is ideal. I will greatly appreciate any and all help. Thank you!

```
        #import "ColorPickerButton.h"
        @implementation ColorPickerButton

        #pragma mark - UIButton Overrides

        + (ColorPickerButton *)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
        {
            return [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        }

        - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
        {
            self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

            if (self)
            {
                r = 0.3;
                g = 0.6;
                b = 0.9;
                [self drawOutline];
                [self drawColor];
            }
            return self;
        }

        - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
        {
            self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
            if (self) {
                // Initialization code
            }
            return self;
        }

        - (void)layoutSubviews
        {
            _outlineLayer.frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 5, 5);
            _colorLayer.frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 5+_outlineLayer.borderWidth,           5+_outlineLayer.borderWidth);
            [super layoutSubviews];
        }

        #pragma mark - Layer setters

        - (void)drawOutline
        {
            if (!_outlineLayer)
            {
                _outlineLayer = [CALayer layer];

                _outlineLayer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
                _outlineLayer.borderWidth = 3;
                _outlineLayer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:170.0/255.0 green:170.0/255.0 blue:170.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor];
                _outlineLayer.opacity = 0.6;

                [self.layer insertSublayer:_outlineLayer atIndex:1];
            }
        }

        - (void)drawColor
        {
            if (!_colorLayer)
            {
                _colorLayer = [CALayer layer];
            }

            _colorLayer.cornerRadius = 16.0;
            _colorLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0] CGColor];
            _colorLayer.opacity = 1.0;

            [self.layer insertSublayer:_colorLayer atIndex:2];
        }

        - (void)changeColorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue
        {
            r = red;
            g = green;
            b = blue;
            [self drawColor];
        }
        @end
```

Comment: Agreed that though it is not the best way to create a border, you can always use rounded corners to achieve the desired goal. One reason it is good is that you  won't be drawing the unnecessary border as that is a pretty heavy operation as compared to rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

We do this in our app. We use the CALayer on the button and add rounded corners 1/2 the size of the component width. We add a border to the button and then set the button background color to achieve the 'fill' color. Works well.